# Is there any method to know if an element is focused using Dalek.js?

Tags: javascript, dalekjs

I am searching for something like:

`assert.isFocused('input.myDefaultInput')`

So far the only workaround I could find is

`assert.exists('input.myDefaultInput:focus')`

Is there any better option?

Comment: From the docs, it doesn't look like there's an option for that. You can request the functionality in a github issue, or be adventurous and fork and make a pull request on the [assertions module](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek-internal-assertions).

Answer (score 2):

The current DalekJS [assertions API](http://dalekjs.com/docs/assertions.html) does not have a method that tests if an element has focus.

The following helper method uses the [execute](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-execute) function to assert if an element has focus using native JavaScript:

```
focused: function(test, selector, message) {
    return test
        .execute(function(selectorParam, messageParam){
            var expectedEl = window.document.querySelector(selectorParam);
            var activeEl = window.document.activeElement;
            this.assert.ok(expectedEl === activeEl, messageParam);
        }, selector, message);
}
```

I wrote a more detailed write-up in a blog post here: http://hady.geek.nz/blog/dalek-element-has-focus/